# Change File Permission in Python File System

Tags: python

I want to change permission of file inside python file system (pyfilesystem).

Here's the code I have:

```
fslocal = fs.osfs.OSFS(localdir, create=True, thread_synchronize=True)
fslocal.setcontents('/file1', b'This is file 1')
```

Now I want to change file permission of file 1. I am using os.chmod for this

```
os.chmod(localdir + '/file1', stat.S_IWOTH)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/scram/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fs/errors.py", line 257, in wrapper

return func(self,*args,**kwds)

File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/scram/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fs/osfs/__init__.py", line 251, in listdir

listing = os.listdir(sys_path)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/user/Documents/tests/function/arwan/localfs/file1
```

Can you please tell me if it is possible to do it and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Try launching this with sudo.

Comment: I think the problem is not on permission effected by sudo command. Instead, it is a permission because we put the file inside a file system. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that it appears you're calling chmod with the intent of adding a single permission bit.  In fact, you are setting all of the permission bits, so the call is trying to clear all of them except the one you want set.  Assuming you're on a Unix system, you will presumably want to set the user and group bits as well, including the read and execute bits.

You can do the following:

```
st = os.stat(path)
old_mode = st.st_mode
new_mode = old_mode | stat.S_IWOTH
os.chmod(path, new_mode)
```

Hopefully that will help you.